# Cognos 11 and Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, cognos

We are in the process of evaluating redshift for our Cognos Analytics 11.0.11 system. We started seeing weird issues when after publishing a package (CQM mode) so we opened a ticket with IBM and they said Cognos works with redshift only in DQM mode. Is this correct? Have you used Cognos in CQM mode?

Answer (score 0):

Not surprising.

The CQM engine is quite old and connects to datasources through native DB drivers (e.g. if you're connecting to Oracle, you have to install and configure the Oracle client on the Cognos server).

The DQM engine is much newer and uses JDBC drivers exclusively (no requirement to install DB client on the Cognos server).